# Swift: exc_breakpoint (code=exc_arm_breakpoint subcode=0xdefe) on prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason I am getting this error when the performSegueWithIdentifier line is reached.

I have this code:

```
if let storedAPIKeychain: AnyObject = dictionary.objectForKey("api_key") {

            println(storedAPIKeychain)

            //This is the line that causes the problems. 
            performSegueWithIdentifier("skipBrandSegue", sender: self)

        }
```

The **println()** works fine and outputs the correct information.

I am trying to pass the **storedAPIKeychain** along with the segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "skipBrandSegue" {

        // Create a new variable to store the instance of the next view controller
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as brandsViewController
        destinationVC.storedAPIKey = storedAPIKeychain!

     }
}
```

Which I thought might have been the problem. however when I changed that line to:

```
destinationVC.storedAPIKey = "someAPIplaceholder"
```

I also get the same error.

Can someone please advise me what this error is and how to resolve it. Thanks.

Edit: Screenshot of error:
[image: Xcode DebugError]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dynamic cast class unconditional indicates that a forced cast failed, because a variable cannot be cast to another type.

In your code I see one cast only at this line:

```
let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as brandsViewController
```

which means the destination view controller is not an instance of `brandsViewController`.

To fix the issue:

- check in interface builder that the custom class property for the destination view controller is correctly set to `brandsViewController`
- check that the segue is actually pointing to that view controller

If none of the above fixes the problem, set a breakpoint at that line and inspect the actual type of the destination view controller.

Side note: by convention, in swift all type names start with uppercase letter, whereas functions, variables and properties with lower case. If you want to make your code readable to other swift developers, I suggest you to stick with that convention (rename `brandsViewController` as `BrandsViewController`)

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Swift/ Xcode and I had forgotten to add the Segue.

Answer (score 4):

@antonios answer should solve your problem. The break is due to the object not being cast (found and assigned).

Just a side note: you're going to have a few issues with this line:

```
if let storedAPIKeychain: AnyObject = dictionary.objectForKey("api_key")
```

especially if you're expecting to get a String from it and pass that between ViewControllers?

Cast it as a String, Create a global scope variable and then assign it to that variable to use - Will be much easier to handle then.

```
var globalVariable = "" //add this line at the top, just before your class declaration. 

if let storedAPIKeychain = dictionary.objectForKey("api_key") as? String {
    self.globalVariable = storedAPIKeychain
}
```

Comment: This helped me a whole bunch.